# What is the regex for this array

Tags: regex, perl

Let's say i have a body of text like this

`["What Color",["Red","Blue","Green","Yellow","Brown","White"]]`

What is the regex to match a color

i try this

```
 while ($mystring =~ m,/"(.*?)"/|,|[/"(.*?)"|,|/],g);
 print "Your Color is : [$1]\n";
```

Can someone help me this perl scripts should print

```
 - Your Color is: Red
 - Your Color is: Blue
 - Your Color is: Green
 - Your Color is: Yellow
 - Your Color is: Brown
 - Your Color is: White
```

Comment: Regex and arrays do not go together.

Comment: Why you will not use JSON http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this text is a valid json string, you can parse it with [`JSON`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON):

```
use JSON;  

my $json = '["What Color",["Red","Blue","Green","Yellow","Brown","White"]]';
print "- Your Color is: $_\n" for @{ decode_json($json)->[1] }
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides being a valid [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON) string, it is also a valid perl structure, which can be extracted by evaluating the string. This may not be practical (or safe!) for all the strings out there, but for this particular one, it works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my $h = eval("['What Color',['Red','Blue','Green','Yellow','Brown','White']]");
my $tag = $h->[0];
my @colors = @{$h->[1]};
say "- Your '$tag' is: $_" for (@colors);
```

**Output:**

```
C:\perl>tx.pl
- Your 'What Color' is: Red
- Your 'What Color' is: Blue
- Your 'What Color' is: Green
- Your 'What Color' is: Yellow
- Your 'What Color' is: Brown
- Your 'What Color' is: White
```